# Finding amount, sum and average of an array and printing it out

Tags: javascript, html

I have to find an amount, the sum and the average of an array. I have this code ready: I know I have to use for loops but the assigment is that I have to use getElementById.innerHTML as well. Any pointers how to go on greatly appreciates. I added the console.log parts as well, though obviously they don't do anything at the moment.

```js
var alkiot = [11, 22, 33, 44];
var x;
var amount;
var sum =0;
var avg;


for (x of alkiot) {
  document.write("taulukko[] " + x + "<br >");
}

console.log("Lukumäärä on" + amount)
console.log("Summa on" + sum);
console.log("Keskiarvo on" + avg);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<div id="myDiv">

<h2>Taulukon [11,22,33,44] läpikäyntiä.</h2>

<p>For- ja for...of- silmukoilla</p>
<hr  ALIGN= LEFT style="height:1px;background-color: black;width:50%; " class="line1">

<p> Alkiot ovat:</p> </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should get used to using MDN to learn about what array iterator methods are available to you. This should get you most of what you need: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Answer (score 1):

```js
var alkiot = [11, 22, 33, 44];
var x;
var sum =0;
var avg;
var amount = alkiot.length;

 sum = alkiot.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
 avg = (sum / alkiot.length) || 0;

console.log("Lukumäärä on: " + amount)
console.log("Summa on: " + sum);
console.log("Keskiarvo on" + avg);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<div id="myDiv">

<h2>Taulukon [11,22,33,44] läpikäyntiä.</h2>

<p>For- ja for...of- silmukoilla</p>
<hr  ALIGN= LEFT style="height:1px;background-color: black;width:50%; " class="line1">

<p> Alkiot ovat:</p> </div>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If i got you right, amount is the number of items in the array, sum is the sum of all the elements, avg is the average. So it's just a matter of calculating each value.

Then you probably will create three elements with respective id inside the html and assign amount, sum and avg in each element

```js
var alkiot = [11, 22, 33, 44];
var x;
var amount;
var sum =0;
var avg;
var amount = alkiot.length;

for (x of alkiot) {
  document.write("taulukko[] " + x + "<br >");
  sum = sum + x;
}
avg = sum/amount;
console.log("Lukumäärä on" + amount)
console.log("Summa on" + sum);
console.log("Keskiarvo on" + avg);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<div id="myDiv">

<h2>Taulukon [11,22,33,44] läpikäyntiä.</h2>

<p>For- ja for...of- silmukoilla</p>
<hr  ALIGN= LEFT style="height:1px;background-color: black;width:50%; " class="line1">

<p> Alkiot ovat:</p> </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The console log is ok but I also have to have the results printed after the list as Amount of numbers: 4, the sum: 110 and the average 27.5. It's not enough to have them in the console log. Any suggestions how to go on about that?